# Routing in laravel 5 with resource

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I've a route:

`Route::resource('partner/register', 'PartnerController\Register');`

And function index, works. But when I try route to store with:

`{!! Form::open(['route'=>'partner/register.store']) !!}`

Error:

> Route [partner/register.store] not defined.

Why? help please.

PD: I used artisan make:controller PartnerController/Register to create the controller. Because need of create controllers in differents directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part is fine I guess as you said you needed it in different directories

```
Route::resource('partner/register', 'PartnerController\Register');
```

But to get the store route use

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => route('partner.register.store')]) !!}
```

Btw you can see all the current routes with `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Thanks... sorry for my terrbile english. I used:
`{!! Form::open(['route'=>'partner.register.store', 'method'=>'POST']) !!}`

Comment: @YrvingHeysenMolinaYriarte Happy that i could help :)